# Как получить позицию скрытого через `display:none` элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как получить позицию скрытого через `display:none` элемента?

### Пример:

```js
console.log('Left: '+ $(".row").offset().left);
```

```css
.row {
  display: none;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">Text</div>
```

Comment: Показываете элемент, берёте его позицию, скрываете элемент

Comment: @Regent, хорошее решение, возьму на заметку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что когда вы применяете `display:none` к элементу, браузер перестает беспокоиться о его рендеринге, поэтому вы не можете получить доступ к интересующим вам параметрам (что возможно при `visibility: hidden`), но здесь есть одна уловка, если вы примените `visibility: hidden`, затем покажете элемент через `display: block` (то есть элемент также невидим, но при этом браузер его отрендрил), получите нужные вам данные и вернете все назад.

### Пример получения параметров скрытого через `display: none` элемента :

```js
//копируем текущие стили в переменную
var previousCss = $(".row").attr("style");

//скрываем элемент через visibility:hidden. даем браузеру сделать рендер 
//через dipslay:block
$(".row")
  .css({
    visibility: 'hidden',
    display: 'block'
  });

//Получаем нужные параметры
let height = $(".row").height();
let width = $(".row").width();
let leftOffset = $(".row").offset().left;
let topOffset = $(".row").offset().top;

console.log('heigth: ' + height);
console.log('width: ' + width);
console.log('leftOffset: ' + leftOffset);
console.log('topOffset: ' + topOffset);

//Применяем начальные стили обратно
$(".row").attr("style", previousCss ? previousCss : "");
```

```css
div.row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">Text</div>
```